# hive jdbc on java get count(*) of table rows

Tags: jdbc, hive

i am trying to get rows count of my table in my java project using jdbc connection to Hive database.

My code:

```
Statement s = con.createStatement();
ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM TABLE_NAME");
r.next();
int count = r.getInt("rowcount") ;
r.close() ;
System.out.println("MyTable has " + count + " row(s).");
```

When i start this function, my project freeze and nothing happens. I tried to debug, the result was: when program reach this place

```
ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM TABLE_NAME");
```

nothing happens and debuger shut down.

`select * from TABLE_NAME` 
works fine, but counting rows from the same table doesnt work. Any ideas? :)

Comment: have you configured Hadoop/Yarn on your post?

Comment: what you mean? i connect to hadoop and hive successfully if you ask me this.

Comment: As you mentioned that `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME `works well but not `SELECT COUNT(*) ` I suspect that you could not trigger a MR job. because the first request do not need a mapreduce job but the latter needs it

Comment: How to trigger it? is it even possible?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguos using of the workd :(. I meant that Hive will start M/R job for all those requests needs count/where/groupBy ..etc. But for those requests which do nothing but getting the whole set of data it will not start an M/R job, rather it will read the data directly from HDFS

Comment: So what i have to do to get count of table rows?

Comment: I need to see the logs from your hive server. it seems that it could  not connect to hadoop. and that's why it could run the COUNT(*) request

Comment: but if select * working, isnt it means that hive can connect to hadoop?

Comment: it means it connect to hadoop, the HDFS part, not necessairaly the computaion part (M/R 2 /Yarn)